# Cookies end up with a wavy bottom

Tags: baking, cookies, batter

My baking papers seem to absorb water a lot. Whenever I bake cookies with a bit wet batter such as lady fingers or cat's tongue, my cookies end up with a not flat but wavy bottom. Is that because of the type of baking papers I used or I did something wrong?

Comment: How long does it take you to pipe out a full tray of cookies? Is the paper wrinkled all over, or only under the cookies you piped first?

Comment: What kind of paper do you use?

Comment: I used this one https://images.app.goo.gl/QKAwSxenoMKEqBnR8

Comment: I notice the paper wrinkled under all cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I would say this is completely normal. It is how paper acts when in contact with liquids.

If you don't like the effect, don't use baking paper under the cookies.